# The number of ways of pressing blue before yellow if all buttons are to be pressed?

Tags: combinatorics

3 buttons are red, 2 are blue and 2 are yellow.
Also, the case when the number of blue and yellow buttons are unequal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the blue and yellow buttons are a single color (blellow). Then ordering the red and blellow button presses is equivalent.